# Oracle SQL JOIN with OR condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to confirm if it is possible to make a JOIn with and OR condition like (for me it is not working):

```
SELECT * FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b
ON table_a.field_1 = table_b.field_1 OR table_a.field_2 = table_b.field_2
```

I tried it an equivalent query, but it was not running. How can I make it work?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible -- any boolean expression is allowed in the `ON` clause, even a subquery.

`OR` is generally a performance killer.

A query such as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a a LEFT JOIN
     table_b b
     ON a.field_1 = b.field_1 OR 
        a.field_2 = b.field_2;
```

Can often be rewritten as:

```
SELECT a.*,
       COALESCE(b1.col, b2.col) as col  -- choose the column value from one of the `b` tables
FROM table_a a LEFT JOIN
     table_b b1
     ON a.field_1 = b1.field_1 LEFT JOIN
     table_b b2 
     ON b2.field_2 = b2.field_2 AND
        b1.field_1 IS NULL    -- no match on other column
```

Two such joins is often much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. Your query is much better as you said. Just to learn a bit more, my original query didn't work. Is it OK? It run for a while and the crushed showing an error related to the fields in the ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using UNION instead of OR ?
Logically, UNION is an equivalent form to OR.
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.field_1 = table_b.field_1 
UNION
SELECT * FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.field_2 = table_b.field_2
;
```

The larger of these two tables should have two indexes (one on field_1 and another on field_2).  The smaller table will be full scanned and then index range scan for the join.